# How do I add quantity in these?

Tags: php, sql

```
    <?php
    $main_subtotal = 0;
    $main_shipping_charge = 0;

    // create a product_id_stack
    $product_id_stack = "";

    foreach ($carts as $key => $cart) {
        $cart_id = $cart['id'];
        $cart_product_id = $cart['product_id'];
        // add product_id to the product_id_stack
        $product_id_stack .= $cart_product_id.",";

        $product = $db->Fetch("*","product","id='$cart_product_id'");

        /*shipping charge formating*/
        if ($product['shipping'] == 0) {
            $shipping_text = "<span class='text-bold text-green'>FREE</span>";
            $shipping_price = 0;
        }else{

            $shipping_text = "".$product['shipping'];
            $shipping_price = $product['shipping'];
        }

        $subtotal = $product['sp'] + $shipping_price;
        echo "
        <td><img src='{$product['image']}' class='cart-image'></td>
        <td>{$product['name']}</td>
        <td>{$product['sp']}.00 php</td>
        <td>{$subtotal}.00 php</td>
        <td><button class='remove-from-cart btn btn-primary text-18' id='{$cart_id}'><i class='fa fa-trash-o'></i></button></td>


        <tr>";

        /*calculate all the shipping charge*/

        $main_shipping_charge = $main_shipping_charge + $shipping_price;
        /*calculate all the sp*/
        $main_subtotal = $main_subtotal + $product['sp'];
    }
?>
```

That is the code in my cart.

and this is the code in adding in the cart

```
    if (isset($_POST['product_id'])) {
        $product_id = ($_POST['product_id']);
        $result = array();
        /*check login status*/
        if (isset($_SESSION['id'])) { /*logged in user*/
            $user_id = $_SESSION['id'];
            $insert = $db->Insert("cart","'','$product_id','$user_id','y',''");

            if ($insert) {
                $result['type'] = "success";
                $result['message'] = "Product has been added to the cart <a href='cart.php' class='text-bd-blue'>View Cart</a>";
            }else{
                $result['type'] = "error";
                $result['message'] = "Error try again.";
            }

        }else{ /* not logged in*/
            $result['type'] = "error";
            $result['message'] = "Please Login <a href='login.php' class='text-bd-blue'>Login</a>";
        }

        echo json_encode($result);
    }
?>
```

Please help me in these codes sir/mam. I also watch videos online but the codes are complicated. i don't know how will i insert quantity in database

**please help me guys i don't know how to do it i'm stock here in 2 months.**

Comment: welcome. So, i assume for now you only able to save to database ?

Comment: or you want add one more insert coloumn ?

Comment: Your question is vague. May I see your `$db->Insert()` body and the table structure you want to insert in.

Comment: sir boby i want to add one more column for the quantity

Comment: if ($insert) {
    /*get the last_inserted_id*/
    $buy_id = mysqli_insert_id($mysqli);
    /*inactive the row from cart table*/
    $update = $db->Query("UPDATE `cart` SET `active`='n',buy_id='$buy_id' WHERE `user_id`='$user_id'");